# Javafx snapshot of defined size

Tags: javafx

Hello I would like to save my line chart to an image of predefined dimensions (x, y). Is there an easy way to do so? I could not find any suitable Snapshot parameter.

```
    WritableImage image = lineChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
```

Thanx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit late, but you should try with the scale of your line chart like this :

```
SnapshotParameters sp =  new SnapshotParameters();
sp.setTransform(Transform.scale(5, 5));
WritableImage image = lineChart.snapshot(sp,null);
```

This set a scale on your linechart of 5. This may improve your image definition too.

Comment: The scaling definitely improves the image quality. Thanks for the tip!